# What minimum moves to convert from given array input to another array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a `source` array `[2, 5, 0, 1, 7]`, now in this array, the requirement says I can use the value `0` in the array as a place holder which I can use to swap elements by only `1` position `left or right`.

```
Eg: moving right the array [2, 5, 0, 1, 7] results in [2, 5, 1, 0, 7]
Eg: moving left the array [2, 5, 0, 1, 7] results in [2, 0, 5, 1, 7]
```

If the index of value `0` is at `starting` or `ending` position then it rotates to the `next` index.

That is if the index of value `0` is at `array.length` then moving right will make this positioned at `array[0]`.

```
Eg: moving right the array [2, 5, 7, 1, 0] results in [0, 2, 5, 7, 1]
```

Similarly, if value `0` is at index `0` of the array then moving left will swap this with `array[array.length]`

```
Eg: moving left the array [0, 5, 7, 1, 2] results in [5, 7, 1, 2, 0]
```

Now find the minimum number of steps required to convert the source array to a given `destination` array `[0, 2, 5, 1, 7]`.

```
Step 1: move 0 from index 2 to index 1 and swap elements

[2, 0, 5, 1, 7]

Step 2: move 0 to left postion
[0, 2, 5, 1, 7]

For this question, the answer should be 2.
```

Just the signature of the problem looks like this:

```
public int getMinimumMoves(int[] a, int[] b) {

}
```

I have below approaches but the time complexity is more.

> Approach 1: Move the array a towards right till a.length times and
>   verify if it matches with array b anywhere.
>
> Approach 2: Move the array a towards left till a.length times and
>   verify if it matches with array b anywhere.

Get the minimum of above two approaches. Also, there can be a chance that the solution may not be possible in which case the code should return `-1`.

Please let me know what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is only one `0` in each array? You can only move array `a`? Is it promised that there is a solution?

Comment: You do not need to really move the array... assuming they `can` match, you can just calculate the minimum between the distances in the zeros from the right and the left (can be done in `O(n)`).

Comment: @Yonlif, 1. yes only one `0` in each array. 2.`You can only move array a`, the requirement does not have any such restriction. 3. There need not be a solution for the given input.

Comment: @Yonlif, I updated my question, there are chances that the given input cannot be converted to the other array, in such case the program should return `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the arrays are of the same size:

```
int size = a.size();
if (size != b.size()) return -1; //size mismatch
```

Rebuild the arrays without the 0 and compare them:

```
int[] c = new int[size - 1];
int[] b = new int[size - 1];
int aIndex = -1;
int bIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == 0) {
        if (aIndex >= 0) return -1; //second occurrence of 0 in a
        aIndex = i;
    }
    else c[aIndex < 0 ? i : i - 1] = a[i];
    if (b[i] == 0) {
        if (bIndex >= 0) return -1; //second occurrence of 0 in b
        bIndex = i;
    }
    else d[bIndex < 0 ? i : i - 1] = b[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
    if (c[i] != d[i]) return -1; //comparison fails
}
if (aIndex < 0 || bIndex < 0) return -1; //0 not present in a or b
```

Return the difference between the indices of the zeros(in a circular array):

```
return Math.min(Math.abs(aIndex - bIndex), Math.abs((aIndex + size) % size) - bIndex);
```

Runtime is O(size).